# SwiftUI - Unable to change color of asset image drawn in canvas

Tags: image, canvas, swiftui, drawing

I'm trying to change the foreground color of an image drawn using the SwiftUI canvas.
It's working with an image from SFSymbols but not working for a custom image in assets.
The image is in format SVG set with "template mode rendering" in assets.
The image is drawn, but stay white.

```
// create canvas to draw
        Canvas { context, size in

                var image = context.resolve(Image("season-drinkfrom")) => not working
                //var image = context.resolve(Image(systemName: "star.fill")) => working
                image.shading = .color(.green)
                
                let imageRect = CGRect(x: drinkFromOriginX - imageSize/2, y: 0, width: imageSize, height: imageSize)
                context.draw(image, in: imageRect)
            }           
            
        }
```

Asset image keeps white foreground color - not working:

[image]

SFSymbol image uses new color (green) - working:

[image]

It's probably a context error for the image.

For info, the asset image set in Assets catalog:

[image]

Comment: Your code works well for me in my tests, on MacOS 13.4, Xcode 14.3, tested on real ios 16 devices (not Previews), and macCatalyst.
It could be different on older systems.

Comment: I tested it on simulator iOS 16 and real device with iOS 16.5. I'm NOT using macCatalyst. Did you test with an asset image ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code and the image I used to test changing the color of a
SVG format image.

The image is "SVG_Logo", downloaded from: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SVG#/media/File:SVG_Logo.svg

and dragged into the `Assets.xcassets` of the Xcode project.

Note, I un-ticked the `Resizing  Preserve Vector Data` and the image turns green, otherwise the image stays the same.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Canvas { context, size in
            var image = context.resolve(Image("SVG_Logo"))
            // var image = context.resolve(Image(systemName: "star.fill"))
            image.shading = .color(.green)
            let imageRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 222, height: 222)
            context.draw(image, in: imageRect)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @workingdog ! The problem was to have ticked "Resizing  Preserve Vector Data" in assets. Good to know !